# gradle subproject dependencies as list of other subprojects

Tags: gradle, dependencies, subproject

How can I get list of a subproject dependecies as list of `Project` object?
`subproject.dependencies` gives list of `DependencyHandler` objects. And I can't find how extract `Project` from `DependencyHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

After a short have found solution myself :)

```
subprojects {
    configurations.all {
        allDependencies.each {
            if (it instanceof ProjectDependency) {
                println it.dependencyProject
            }
        }
    }
}
```